Expo updates have been downloaded, but they are not being applied
I'm using expo 50, "expo-updates": ~0.24.12, Hermes engine.
I'm pretty sure that it's not a configuration problem. I checked:

branch + channel (correct)
A new update is available and is showing on the correct branch.
The runtime version is correct. (I just upgraded to sdk 50 and uses appVersion policy with value 1.0.0, pretty sure I haven't installed any new native dependencies since I upgraded)
I have a .env file with all required environment variables. In fact, I can use this .env file to create development builds with no issues.

While checking logcat, I've found these logs indicate that the update is downloaded successfully, but it is not taking affect.:
{"timestamp":1714912838139,"message":"Updates state change: CheckCompleteAvailable, context = {isUpdateAvailable=true, isUpdatePending=false, isChecking=false, isDownloading=false, isRestarting=false,

{"timestamp":1714912838140,"message":"Updates state change: Download, context = {isUpdateAvailable=true, isUpdatePending=false, isChecking=false, isDownloading=true, isRestarting=false,

{"timestamp":1714912838153,"message":"UpdatesController onBackgroundUpdateFinished: Update available","code":"None","level":"info"}
{"timestamp":1714912838155,"message":"Updates state change: DownloadComplete, context = {isUpdateAvailable=true, isUpdatePending=true, isChecking=false, isDownloading=false, isRestarting=false
{"timestamp":1714912838156,"message":"ErrorRecovery: remote load status changed: NEW_UPDATE_LOADED","code":"None","level":"info"}
{"timestamp":1714912838288,"message":"Emitted event: name = Expo.nativeUpdatesStateChangeEvent, type = check","code":"None","level":"info"}
{"timestamp":1714912838289,"message":"Emitted event: name = Expo.nativeUpdatesStateChangeEvent, type = checkCompleteAvailable","code":"None","level":"info"}
 {"timestamp":1714912838290,"message":"Emitted event: name = Expo.nativeUpdatesStateChangeEvent, type = download","code":"None","level":"info"}
{"timestamp":1714912838290,"message":"Emitted event: name = Expo.nativeUpdatesEvent, type = updateAvailable","code":"None","level":"info"}
{"timestamp":1714912838290,"message":"Emitted event: name = Expo.nativeUpdatesStateChangeEvent, type = downloadComplete","code":"None","level":"info"}

I've followed both Basic and Advanced troubleshooting documents but to no avail.
My app.json has this config:
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "enabled": true,
      "requestHeaders": {
        "expo-channel-name": "preview" -- set a specific channel for a local debug build
      },
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/<my-id>"
    },


Any updates regarding this?
I have tried adding this:
runtimeVersion: {
  policy: 'appVersion',
},

to my app.config.js and am now waiting for the build. I've read somewhere that it should work after this change, and will update this answer if it does.
